# Resizing images on mouse over (Javascript/MooTools)

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've built a webpage that's supposed to increase the size of images onmouseover. 
I'm not replacing the images with bigger ones but rather "stretch" the existing ones because of system limitations.

Here's the webpage:
http://www.catmoviez.com/IMDBQueries.aspx

You can see that the movie images get bigger when you're on them.

**Problem is when I move my mouse too quick that sometimes an image gets stuck open or it causes inifinite flickering.**

attached is also the code I'm using for the resize:

```
function resizeImage(elem,width,height){
    var myEffect = new Fx.Morph(elem, {duration: 350});
    myEffect.start({'height': height,'width': width});
}
```

Comment: My office proxy says your link is a malicious site.

Comment: That's not nice. I'm sure you can enter it by IP. http://109.66.48.12 . It's a dynamicIP site so many websites live on this domain. I'm sure some are malicious. Mine is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, set this variable outside your functions

```
var imagegrow
```

And then mouseover this

```
function () {
    imagegrow = setTimeout(function(){ resizeImage(elem,width,height); },1000);
}
```

And the mouseout this:

```
function () {
    clearTimeout(imagegrow);
}
```

Adjust the `1000` number to suit your preferred delay (it's in milliseconds). I'd write the whole code for you, but I haven't used MooTools for a while.

Comment if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please bear in mind I have dozens of images in the webpage. Will it not be a problem?

Comment: Got a syntax error. Wrote <img ... onmouseover="function(){imagegrow...}" /> Got a syntax error on the first brackets (for the "function" keyword)

Comment: Ah ok I was assuming you'd be setting the events on document load. In you're adding it as the onmouseover attribute, miss off the `function(){` at the beginning and the `}` at the end and it'll work. Also, there should be no problem with the amount of images you have. Make sure you declare the imagegrow variable outside of everything.

In any case, I would suggest using addEvent rather than specifying the events inline, it makes for shorter, neater and more maintainable code in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Faruz, Gaussie is right you need to use a timeout. However, consider using mootools' addEvent function as described in the [mootools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event) as well as the [$$ function](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#dollar) which will allow you to achieve something much more elegant, along the lines of:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $$("tr td input").addEvent("mouseover", function() {
    //anonymous function like Gaussie's here
  });
});
```

Note that this isn't the exact code, it will take some modification but it is cleaner and should be more efficient then setting the onmouseover property of every image. Also, remember this goes in the head of your HTML document.